# Please clarify the meaning of "The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"

Tags: c#

I am developing a C# Console application, that has nothing to do with the server but it does use a library vcamcomlib which comes with the trial version of e2e vcam.

These are my lines of code

```
refByte = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filepath");

vcam.PlayBuffer(ref refByte[0], 640, 480);//Exception comes here
```

My program was running fine yesterday, however i started my system today and trying to run it. the exception just showed up.
Can somebody help?
Thanks alot

Comment: Check the system logs to see if you can get more information about the exception. It's likely to be a memory leak error in the third-party component. Have you used the component successfully before for a relatively lengthy period of time?

Comment: @Cody Gray, I have been using it for one day only, ill check right in the log and will post here

Comment: If it is a trial version, the library might need to connect to their server for validation. Not sure about it but it is possible because of RPC(Remote Procedure Call) error message.

Comment: @eSPiYa That may be the case, i have sent a query to support.

Comment: @eSPiYa I had mailed their support team, they said this issue never occured before. So I guess its the issue on my side. Can you help me by telling me why this type of exception usually comes? Or what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, I might be wrong about the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [URL](http://forums.asp.net/t/1308404.aspx), they discussed about the COM interop and thread safety. Better ask them which components are safe in multi-threading and which are not.